# C# : Check wether HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(myURL) was successful?

Tags: c#, http, stream, httprequest, visual-studio-2019

I am using the GetStreamAsync-Method in order to read in a file through a stream.
But I am wondering: What happens if the URL provided is currently not available? How would I know if GetStreamAsync failed?

Here is the code I am working with:

```
var tmpMyDataFile = Path.GetTempFileName();       
using (var myDataStream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(MyURL))
{
    using (var tmpMyDataStream = File.OpenWrite(tmpMyDataFile))
    {
        await myDataStream.CopyToAsync(tmpMyDataStream);
    }
}
```

Do I have to do this through catching the HttpRequestException exception or is there some sort of StatusCode I could retrieve somehow?
If I have to do this via exception catching, what exactly is the meaning of the TaskCanceledException described in the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=net-5.0

TaskCanceledException: The request failed due to timeout. <- Which timeout?

Comment: Use following which returns an HttpResponseMessage.  The response has status code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

> What happens if the URL provided is currently not available? How would I know if GetStreamAsync failed?

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetStreamAsync_System_Uri_), you'll get an `HttpRequestException`. You can check the status code (if any) using its [`StatusCode` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception.statuscode?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpRequestException_StatusCode).

> Do I have to do this through catching the HttpRequestException exception or is there some sort of StatusCode I could retrieve somehow?

If you want to *avoid* the exception, then you should use [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_), which returns an `HttpResponseMessage` with a `StatusCode`. Note that `SendAsync` will still throw an exception if it is unable to get any response at all.

> If I have to do this via exception catching, what exactly is the meaning of the TaskCanceledException

Only on .NET Core and .NET 5+ only, `TaskCanceledException` indicates a timeout. By default, [`HttpClient.Timeout` is set to 100 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-5.0). If you need to handle timeout exceptions, I recommend catching `OperationCanceledException` rather than `TaskCanceledException`.